# XSLT: Delete certain characters from string with nested elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, tei

I have a sequence of transformations that result with a penultimate output containing a code line of the following structure:

```
<hi rendition="#rf-Lyricist">
   [Lyricist: <anchor xml:id="w1s"/>Some Name]<anchor xml:id="w1e"/>
</hi>
```

Transforming the tei:hi element into  is not a problem. The square brackets surrounding the text should be transformed into a nested tei:supplied, so the desired result is:

```
<note type="lyricist">
   <supplied reason="provided-by-editor" cert="1" resp="#NN">
      Lyricist: <anchor xml:id="w1s"/>Some Name<anchor xml:id="w1e"/>
    </supplied>
</note>
```

I tried several ways of achieving this, inlcuding:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[1]/tei:lg/tei:l/tei:hi[(@rendition='#rf-Lyricist')]">
    <!-- This method deletes all tei:anchor within the lyricist line. -->
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[.*\]">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:element name="note" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'lyricist'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="supplied" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="reason">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'provided-by-editor'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="cert">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="resp">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'#ND'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '[]', '')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

I always get a result, where not only the square brackets, but also the tei:anchor elements are deleted, such as:

```
<note type="lyricist">
   <supplied reason="provided-by-editor" cert="1" resp="#ND">
      Lyricist: Some Name
   </supplied>
</note>
```

The same method for replacing square brackets works perfectly well within a text node that has no further elements inside.

Comment: I don't quite get why the square brackets in the input around e.g. `Lyricist: <anchor xml:id="w1s"/>Some Name]` result in an output wrapper `supplied` element of the white space before that and also the `anchor` element behind that. As for the problem, I think, given the mixed contents of text and `anchor` elements being contained inside of the square brackets, a two step solution that first transforms square brackets into some elements (e.g. `<osb/>` and `<csb/>`) and in the second steps uses `for-each-group group-starting-with="osb"` and `group-ending-with="csb"` will give better results.

Answer (score 0):

To implement "The square brackets surrounding the text should be transformed into a nested [..]supplied" I would use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="hi">
    <note type="lyricist">
      <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="brackets-to-elements"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$content/node()" group-starting-with="osb">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::osb">
              <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-ending-with="csb">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position() eq 1">
                    <supplied>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(position() = last())]"/>
                    </supplied>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </note>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="brackets-to-elements" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="hi//text()" mode="brackets-to-elements">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\[|\]')" mode="analyze"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match[. = '[']" mode="analyze">
    <osb/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match[. = ']']" mode="analyze">
    <csb/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is the approach outlined in my comment, that is, to use one pass to find and convert square brackets in text nodes inside of `hi` elements to elements like e.g. `osb` and `csb` and a second pass on that intermediary tree to use standard/classic pairs of `for-each-group group-starting-with="osb"/group-ending-with="csb" to establish the wrapper element.

Output is e.g.

```
<note type="lyricist">
   <supplied>Lyricist: <anchor xml:id="w1s"/>Some Name</supplied><anchor xml:id="w1e"/>
</note>
```